# How do I create a Monitor for a Specific Log in DataDog

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

Hi I'm fairly new to DataDog and I want to create a new monitor to look into one of my services to find a specific log like so “Unable to get latest Previously Acquired Files state. Please try again.” How should I go about doing this?

[image]

I am currently going through the tutorials and am looking at various ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer to my own question. Since in this example I wanted to look at a specific service (this being "cloudwatch" for my example) you would then add that to the query along with the log information you're looking for. This then looks for any logs within that service matching your description.

[image: EXAMPLE]